# Change AngularJS url/route from html - javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Say I have a button that's within the `ng-app` scope, but outside the `ng-controller`/`ng-view` scope.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
    <div ng-view> <!-- angular-view --> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to change the URL/Route when I click the button.

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //code that changes path.
});
```

How do I do that? If I try `window.location.href = '/';` the whole page gets reloaded, not just the view. `$location` isn't visible from html javascript, so that's not an option neitehr.

If anyone knows a way I can change the path/route/url from javascript, I'd be more than happy to accept any valid answer, or a redirect to some helpful documentary post, or a rederect to another SO question, because I'm trying to find an answer to this for a while and I've got nothing...

I'll note that I tried making a global scope function, but that didn't work, neither.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .config( ... )
    .run(function($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.setUrl = function(url) {
            $location.path(url);
        };
    })
    .controller(
        .....
```

and called with `setUrl('/');`, `$root.setUrl('/');` and `$rootScope.setUrl('/');`, but still nothing (`'undefined'`).

**note**: the button script is just an example, the real purpose why I'm asking this is a little bit larger, so I'm trying to simplify.

Comment: it should work with $rootScope

Comment: this might help http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/nukRe/light/

Comment: @jonasnas unfortunately, doesn't. it returns it as 'undefined function'.

Comment: are you calling it like this: `ng-click="setUrl('/somePath')"` ?

Comment: did, but still didn't work properly. while it doesn't crash, nor report bugs, it still doesn't actually change the location path.

Comment: if you use baseURL you might need to pass 'somePath' instead of '/somePath'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose is to change route from outside of the Angular app, then you need to change location hash part:

```
window.location.hash = 'new-route';
```

Inside Angular controller use [$location.path](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path) method.

Comment: only problem with this is, they don't want the hash to be implemented in the URL, so I have set up `$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });`